# Перенаправить на разные страницы в зависимости от результатов запроса

Tags: javascript, php, html

(Новичок) Пишу сайт с php-бэкэндом. Встрял на странице входа в аккаунт. Столкнулся с задачей: на php выполняю запрос к бд. В зависимости от результата запроса мне нужно либо вернуться на исходный html, а в js передать некое значение (условно bool error), либо перейти на другой html, передав ему немного другое значение. Как можно провернуть сию операцию?
Примерный код:

```
  php:
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, 
    "select
        `account_id`
    from
        accounts
    where
        `account_login` = '$login' and `account_password` = '$password'
    ");
  html:
    <form class="form__login" action="login.php" method="post">
      <div class="error__login" style="color: red;"></div>
      <div class="input">
        <input 
          type="text"
          class="input__login"
          name="login"
          placeholder="Логин">
        <input 
          type="text"
          class="input__login"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Пароль">
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Войти</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  js:
    if (error) {
        $('.error__login').append('Неверный логин или пароль!');
    }
```

Comment: Погуглите, что такое AJAX

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($result[0]['account_id'])) {
    // некоторые действия, связанные с успешной авторизацией. к примеру, запись в сессию идентификатора

    // перенаправление на следующую страницу
    header('Location: http://mysite.ru/nextpage');
} else {
    // сообщение об ошибке
    echo 'error';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из описания задачи не совсем понял каким методом Вам это нужно сделать. Так что, тут два способа реализации - в `PHP` - как выше написал @bars либо методом отправки `ajax`-запроса к `php`-файлу который отдаст ответ и зависимости от этого ответа уже перенаправлять на нужную страницу уже с помощью `js`

```js
 $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'login='+$('.form__login input[type=text][name=login]').val()+'&password='+$('.form__login input[type=password][name=password]').val(),
            error: function(req, text, error) {
                alert('Ajax Error:'+error);  
            },
            success: function ( data) {
                if ( data ) {
                   if ( parseInt(data['code']) == 1) {
                       window.location='/profile.php';
                   } else { alert('Неверное имя пользователя или пароль!'); }
                } else { alert('Unknown server response!'); }
            },
        });
```

Ну и `login.php`

```php
$login = $_POST["login"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, 
    "select
        `account_id`
    from
        accounts
    where
        `account_login` = '$login' and `account_password` = '$password'
    ");
    $result = [];
    if(!empty($result[0]['account_id'])) {
       //Успешно авторизованы - возвращаем код 1
       $result['code'] = 1;
    } else {
       //Не нашли такого пользователя либо неверный пароль - возвращаем код 0
       $result['code'] = 0;
    }
    echo json_encode( $result);
```